# Is it possible to nest the all function?

Tags: python

I have a list of objects named *items*. Each object has a property *state* and a property *children*, which is another list of objects. And each child object has also a property named *state*. What I want to know is if every item and their children are in the states *happy* or *cheerful*.

I did this with all (only analysing the states of the items):

```
if all(item.state in ['happy', 'cheerful'] for item in items):
   pass
```

I would like to know which is the best way to do the same with not only items but children too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeking for some recursion here:

```
def is_happy(items):
   return all(item.state in ['happy', 'cheerful'] for item in items) and all(is_happy(item.childs) for item in items)
```

As @tobias_k pointed out this should be quicker since it iterates only once on items:

```
def is_happy(items):
   return all(item.state in ['happy', 'cheerful'] and is_happy(item.childs) for item in items)
```

It is at least more readable.

In the case you only have two layers of objects a simple for might do the trick too.

```
def is_happy(items):
    happy_children = True
    for item in items:
        if any(child.state not in ['happy', 'cheerful'] for child in item):
            happy_children = False
            break
    return all(item.state in ['happy', 'cheerful'] for item in items) and happy_children
```

Comment: I'd rather just a basic `for` loop in this simple case, unless OP has many more layers to deal with.

Comment: Or shorter: `all(item.state in ['happy', 'cheerful'] and is_happy(item.childs) for item in items)`

Comment: I think OP was speaking of more than one layer.

Comment: I assumed he had only the `2` mentioned, in which case recursion would be slower and overkill

Comment: I added the solution with a for just in case :)

Comment: Can you turn "for items in items" into "for item in items"? I'm not able to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this would be the right way:

```
if all(item.state in ['happy', 'cheerful'] and all(c.state in ['happy', 'cheerful'] for c in item.childs) for item in items):
   pass
```

Comment: `all(item.childs.state in ['happy', 'cheerful'])` I doubt that this will work. `item.childs` is some sort of list and does not have attribute `state`. I guess this should be `all(c.state in [...] for c in item.childs)`

Answer (score 1):

First step: flatten the list of items:

```
def flatten(items):
    for item in items:
        yield item
        for child in getattr(item, 'children', ()):
            yield child
```

Or using Python 3.4+:

```
def flatten(items):
    for item in items:
        yield item
        yield from getattr(item, 'children', ())
```

And now you can iterate through flattened items using `all(..)` or some other way:

```
is_happy = lambda item: getattr(item, 'state') in ('happy', 'cheerful')
are_happy = lambda items: all(map(is_happy, flatten(items)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is your friend here

```
def happy(x):
    return (x.state in ('happy', 'cheerful') and
            all(happy(xc) for xc in x.children))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably best done manually.

```
def valid(item):
    return item.state in ['happy', 'cheerful']

for item in items:
    if not (valid(item) and all(valid(child) for child in item)):
        break
else:
    # success
```

Changing the generator expression to work with this is possible but makes it a bit hacky.

```
if all(child.state in ['happy', 'cheerful'] for item in items for child in item+[item]):
   pass
```

So to answer your question, yes its possible to nest the `all` function and thats how you could do it if you really wanted.